How to build a Flutter app with the impeller enabled?
Nowadays Flutter sets the impeller as the default rendering engine.
But some mobile devices don't support Vulkan and also many GPUs without Vulkan support.
When you run the Flutter app with impeller on such devices, app is either crashing or UI glitches a lot.
https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/impeller
Is there any way to run the Flutter app without problem on both devices without specifying the enable/disable impeller?
For example, Flutter Web uses the SKIA engine for PC browsers but uses the HTML engine for mobile browsers automatically.
So it would be great to find a way to build the Flutter app without specifying impeller enable/disable, but it detects and uses the proper rendering engine automatically.

Impeller already does what you're asking automatically and actually doesn't depend on Vulkan. On iOS and macOS, Impeller uses Metal, not Vulkan. On Android, it uses Vulkan if available, and otherwise falls back on OpenGL.
From the page you linked:

Impeller uses, but doesn't depend on, features available in modern
APIs like Metal and Vulkan.


Flutter enables Impeller by default on Android. On devices that don't
support Vulkan, Impeller will fallback to the the legacy OpenGL
renderer. No action on your part is necessary for this fallback
behavior.

